# Updating the edge weight displayed without being "cluncky"

Tags: java, awt, jgrapht, jgraph

I am using Jgrapht to build a simulation environment based on a directed weighted graph. I now want to display the simulation using Jgraph.

While I have figured out how to display the graph and update it as the simulation runs, I have noticed that when the edge weights update, the entire window flickers. Presently I an calling `frame.paintComponents()` to update the window.

I believe that I can get it to only update the individual edges that are changing, but I am not familiar with `java.awt`.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
{

    Simulation newSim = new Simulation(31, .01);//extends ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph

    SimulationViewer applet = new SimulationViewer(newSim);//extends JApplet
    applet.init();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
    frame.setTitle("Simulation Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


    //run simulation
    for (;newSim.getStep() < newSim.getMAX_STEP(); newSim.incrementStep()) {
        BreadthFirstIterator<SimulationBlock, Signal> iter = 
                         new BreadthFirstIterator<SimulationBlock, Signal>(newSim, newSim.head);

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            iter.next().execute(newSim);
            //update graphics
            frame.paintComponents(applet.getGraphics());//looks clunky
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to call the `update` method for applet. Replaced:

```
frame.paintComponents(applet.getGraphics());//looks clunky
```

With:

```
applet.update(applet.getGraphics());
```

This looks a little funky and maybe I need to refactor this code so that is within the `SimulationViewer` class.